# why are there multiple alternatives?

Tags: antlr

I have a simple grammar trying to parse 2 types of text, the line started with "#include" and others. Here is my grammar:

```
cmds
    : cmd+
    ;

cmd
    : include_cmd |  other_cmd
    ;

include_cmd
    : INCLUDE  DOUBLE_QUOTE  FILE_NAME  DOUBLE_QUOTE
    ;

other_cmd
    : (~'#')+
    ;


INCLUDE
    : '#include'
    ;

DOUBLE_QUOTE
    : '"'
    ;

FILE_NAME
    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')+
    ;

New_Line 
    : ('\r' | '\n')+   
    ;

WS 
    : ('\t' | ' ')+  {$channel = HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

But I get such warning:

```
Decision can match input such as "INCLUDE DOUBLE_QUOTE FILE_NAME DOUBLE_QUOTE" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2

As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

I am not sure how to interpret this warning. The example in it, "INCLUDE DOUBLE_QUOTE FILE_NAME DOUBLE_QUOTE", should only match include_cmd since "other_cmd" does not start with "#".

Could you help what is going on here?

I am using antlr3.4.

UPDATE - Thanks for greydet suggestion, after changing other_cmd rule to (~INCLUDE)+, that warning is gone. But there is another warning actually,

```
Decision can match input such as "{DOUBLE_QUOTE..FILE_NAME, New_Line..WS}" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2

As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

Now I guess this is because a double quote can match both other_cmd rule and DOUBLE_QUOTE rule, but I am wondering here, one is parser rule and the other is lexer rule, does this warning make sense? I can not to use DOUBLE_QUOTE at all but directly use " in parser rule include_cmd, but that makes not easy reading.

Any help to clear this warning?

A side question - the warning message just says alternative 1,2, but it is not immediately clear to me what is 1 and what is 2, is there a way to render antlr to give more direct alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `other_cmd` rule will match every token sequence which does not start with a `#` token.
The `include_cmd` rule will match a sequence which start with a `#include` token.

Since `#` and `#include` are two different tokens, a token sequence which start with a `#include` token match both rules.

Try with the following rule:

```
other_cmd
    : (~INCLUDE)+
    ;
```